aria2: Using multiple connections; and using 'show-files' without downloading '.torrent' file first
I try to understand the basics how aria2 works and I have two questions.
In one article I read:

To download a file using more than one connection to each host, use
aria2c -x2 http://site.com/file.zip


My first question is what does it mean on the practical side? What are the benefits and pitfalls of doing so instead of just aria2c http://site.com/file.zip?
And my second question is how to use --show-files without downloading the torrent file first. For example, this works fine:
aria2c --show-files ./file.torrent

But this returns me the This file is neither Torrent nor Metalink file error:
aria2c --show-files https://releases.ubuntu.com/24.04/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent


This file is neither Torrent nor Metalink file. Skipping.

